# Do British children say "I am in the first year"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

I noticed the American use "grade" and British use "year" to refer levels on a school.

Normally, American will say "**Sam is in first grade**" and British will say "**Sam is in year one**".

Do American say "**Sam is in grade one**"?

Do British say "**Sam is in first year**"?

Comment: Not an answer as I haven't been anywhere near a school in 45 years, but they certainly said 'first year', & not first grade *or* year one, when I was there. Not only were you *in* first year , but you *were* a first year, too; or a first former (I'm a first year; I'm in [the] first year/form; I'm a first-former)[depending on whether your school was secondary moder/comprehensive or a more formal grammar school. First year was 11 years old, back when you only went to two schools, junior & senior.

Comment: There's no single answer to this question because the UK has two different education systems. Scotland has a different system from the other countries in the UK (England, Wales and Northern Ireland). I Can't tell you much about the rest of the UK, but in Scotland currently, Primary School levels are P1 to P7 (ages 5 to 11 approx). High School  (Secondary School) from years S1 to S6 (ages 12 to 18 approx), these High School levels are sometimes called "First year", "Second year", etc but this may be considered old fashioned now. The kids nowadays I think just say P1, P2, S1, S2, etc,.